# How to override flask-table class

Tags: python, flask

I'm trying to override flask-table class to add some columns depending on options.

Currently I'm generating route:

```
@app.route("/delete_database", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def delete_database():
    table_content = Databases.query.all()
    table2 = DatabasesTable(table_content)
    # table2.add_column(col=LinkCol("Delete", endpoint="index"), name="witam")
    response = make_response(render_template("delete_database.html", title="Delete database", table=table2))
    return response
```

view:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block app_content %}

        <div class="row" style="padding:2%">
            {{ table }}
        </div>

{% endblock %}
```

table class:

```
    from flask_table import Table, Col, LinkCol,
class DatabasesTable(Table):

    def sort_url(self, col_id, reverse=False):
        pass

    classes = ['table table-hover']
    table_id = "databases_table"
    id = Col("Column name")
    name = Col("Column name")
    service = Col("Column name")
    description = Col("Column name")
    count = Col("Column name")
    timestamp = Col("Column name")
    some_db_table = Col("Column name")
    some_db_table2 = Col("Column name")
    some_db_table3 = Col("Column name")
    some_db_table4 = Col("Column name")
    more = LinkCol("Column name")
```

Everything works perfectly but I would like to add column Edit with delete buttons depending on route options (for example check if user is moderator and then add column with delete button).

I have tried already:

```
class DatabasesTable(Table):

    def __init__(self, new_options=None):
        self.new_options = new_options
        super().__init__(self)

    def sort_url(self, col_id, reverse=False):
        pass

    classes = ['table table-hover']
    table_id = "databases_table"
    id = Col("Column name")
    name = Col("Column name")
    service = Col("Column name")
    description = Col("Column name")
    count = Col("Column name")
    timestamp = Col("Column name")
    some_db_table = Col("Column name")
    some_db_table2 = Col("Column name")
    some_db_table3 = Col("Column name")
    some_db_table4 = Col("Column name")
    more = LinkCol("Column name")
    if options["edit"]:
        edit = Column_with_Delete_button
```

but I have error:

```
TypeError: 'DatabasesTable' object is not iterable
```